# PushSharp throwing CryptographicException: Certificate instance is empty

Tags: c#, pushsharp

I can't get PushSharp to work, I'm pretty sure the problem is something I'm doing incorrectly, though I have no idea what... :/

Here's the code:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(
                "cio_aps_development.p12",
                "",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

//var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, "cio_aps_development.p12", "");
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, cert);
```

It doesn't matter which approach I take, I get this error:

`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Certificate instance is empty.`

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Certificate instance is empty.
      at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper.ThrowIfContextInvalid (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateImpl impl) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Helper.cs:120 
      at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.get_Impl () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate.cs:137 
      at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_Impl () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs:63 
      at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_IssuerName () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs:169 
      at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConfiguration.CheckIsApnsCertificate () [0x00011] in <1389cefdb7bb4d6c97d6126934847d24>:0 
      at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConfiguration.Initialize (PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConfiguration+ApnsServerEnvironment serverEnvironment, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate, System.Boolean validateIsApnsCertificate) [0x000a8] in <1389cefdb7bb4d6c97d6126934847d24>:0 
      at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConfiguration..ctor (PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConfiguration+ApnsServerEnvironment serverEnvironment, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate) [0x00006] in <1389cefdb7bb4d6c97d6126934847d24>:0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

The problem was my p12 file. It hadn't been properly exported. 
After exporting it the right way, it worked.